# Asp.net website homepage does not show default.aspx

Tags: asp.net, url, iis

I'm new to asp.net, but have a question I cant find answer to (googled for a while now).
My problem is:

I got my website running on a IIS 8.5.

When I visit the site, the url does not show the /default.aspx on the ending. only http://www.mywebsite.com/
I want it to automatically show http://www.mywebsite.com/default.aspx when I visit my home page, just as in html..

The website is up and running fine. But I got a graphic error with some highlighting since the page isn't /default.aspx

I got a temporary fix of adding a redirect rule, but want it permanently inside the webpage since I'm going to make more asp.net sites.

EDIT: Code added:

Using the following js for highlighting:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
             var url = window.location.pathname;
             var substr = url.split('/');
             var urlaspx = substr[substr.length - 1];
             $('.nav').find('.active').removeClass('active');
             $('.nav li a').each(function () {
                 if (this.href.indexOf(urlaspx) >= 0) {
                     $(this).parent().addClass('active');
                 }
             });
         });
     </script>
```

And following for the nav-bar list:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navHeaderCollapse"> 
                <ul class ="nav navbar-nav  navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a runat="server" href="~/default.aspx">Hjem</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/lenker.aspx">Lenker</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/kontakt.aspx">Kontakt</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: Check if the IIS setup has a `HTTP Redirect` for the website. If there is one you may need to remove/change it.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious - default.aspx is in the list of default documents?

Comment: How would you handle users that navigate to your website without explicitly adding a file? You should focus on fixing the error which should either _not_ be dependent on it, or handle both cases. Hth.

Comment: IIS have no http redirects.

default.aspx is in the list of default documents yes.

I got the default.aspx file in the root dir of the website. when not got that filename in the address, all the links in the navbar is highlighted..